# scrape web page for certain data

Tags: jquery

We are creating a script.

Essentially user enters into a formfield :3358928
OnSubmit ajax, visits the page below appending the numeric string the user entered into the url.

http://www.fairtrading.qld.gov.au/ftlr/Default.aspx?ResultType=LNum&LNum=3358928&LType=REAL%20ESTATE&Page=1

On that url, is a first name and a surname.
How would we scrape the first name and surname, and echo it back to our form.

Essentially the issue arises, from scraping the page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does that domain belong to you? If not, you can't do what you want because AJAX can only retrieve pages from the same domain.

Comment: I thought that ajax could now be configured to visit ext domains.
as in: http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/feb13/

Comment: In fact Snook.ca and many others implement cross domain ajax requests. One such example is http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your web server must be set up to proxy all of the client's requests. Otherwise, the third-party server [would have to send an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) and the visitor's browser would have to support cross-domain XMLHttpRequest. (Flash/Silverlight similarly requires a crossdomain.xml file.)

This is exactly the way http://ajax-cross-domain.com/ works. (That particular proxy script just happens to JavaScript-encode the third-party server's response.)

I noticed that the particular page includes an XHTML doctype, which seemed to indicate you could use the `responseXML` property of *native* XMLHttpRequest or jQuery (as opposed to AJAX Cross Domain) to take advantage of the browser's XML parser. Unfortunately, this is just another web site that outputs invalid XML — it does not encode ampersands correctly as `&amp;`.

Thus you will most likely resort to regular expressions, which is [not ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Most probably, the simplest approach is to find the text of the `td` elements (relying on the fact that the exact same tag is not nested):

```
// Creating the regexp object    
var regex = /<td class="BodyFont">(.*?)<\/td>/g;

// Execute this line of code as many times as needed.
contentsOfNextTd = regex.exec(textOfThePage)[1];
```

Sort of ugly, considering that it would be much simpler if only we had valid XML to work with. And if you have the option, I would recommend scraping the page on your own server and returning a nicely-formatted JSON or XML response — you need a server-side proxy anyways and it will keep the client-side code simpler.

Comment: Hiya Ideal, yeah unfortunately that tag is repeated countless times.
Great response tho, ticked :)